# Django from is not being past into html template

Tags: html, python-3.x, django, forms

As in the question title `"{{form}}"` from  is not being loaded into html template I checked by previous projects I have almost the same code, differences are required fields, naming etc. mechanic is the same.
In those projects registration function works perfectly here it's not even throwing an error just don't display anything.
No wonder what might be wrong in here.

forms.py

```py
    from django import forms
    from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm    
    from .models import Profile 
    
    class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
        email = forms.EmailField(max_length=60, help_text="Required field")    
    
        class Meta:
            model = Profile
            fields = ["email", "username", "password", "password2", "calories_plan", "diet_type"]
```

views.py

```py
    def registration_view(request):
        context = {}
        if request.POST:
            form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                email = form.cleaned_data.get("email")
                password = form.cleaned_data.get("password")
                new_account = authenticate(email=email, password=password)
                login(request, new_account)
            else:
                context["registration_form"] = form
        else:
            form = RegistrationForm()
            context["registration_form"] = form
        return render(request, "Account/registration.html", context)
```

html template

```html
    {% extends 'main.html' %}
    {% load crispy_forms_tags %}
    
    {% block content %}
    
        <div class="content-section">
            <form method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <fieldset class="form-group">
                    <legend class=border-bottom mb-4>Join today                     
                        {{ form }}
                    </legend>
                </fieldset>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Sign Up</button>
                </div>          
            </form>
    
            <div class="border-top pt-3">
                <small class="text-muted">
                    Already have an account?
                    <a href="#" class="ml-2">
                        Log In
                    </a>
                </small>
            </div>
        </div>
    
    {% endblock %}
```

And how it looks in browser.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing `'registration_form'` to the context, but in template you are calling `{{ form }}`.

Replace:
`{{ form }}`
with:
`{{ registration_form }}`